# Windows CE Generate Log on Barcode Scan

Tags: vb.net, windows-ce, barcode

At the moment, I am currently faced with a small project as to update a current bar-code system so that it will store a log file on scan. However, I'm not provided with any source code for the current system. So I was thinking maybe I can develop a small .exe to run and it's job is just to store the ID scanned as well as the current timestamp to a text file named log.txt.

Here's all I'm provided with:

1. A small touchscreen device running on windows CE with a built-in bar-code
   scanner (imager) and few other ports including a USB port.
2. A memory stick containing the object codes (exe, dll, pdb, bat and
   xml) and other multimedia files.
3. SDK CD containing an SDK platform installer (.msi) requiring VS2005
   SP1 to be installed.

Now I'm just confused on how to get the job done. I've been spending the past 3 days researching about this. One of my Google findings suggest that the bar-code scanner works just like a keyboard input? Hence, I made a simple VB6 application with a textbox to store the contents of it and reset the textbox at the same time when a 10-digit ID is inputted. The application is not executable in the device though (I found out that VB6 exe is not executable in winCE, sadly).

Furthermore, I tried to open MS WordPad in the device and attempted to scan the bar-code. Nothing is copied to the WordPad though. I thought bar-code scanner works identically like a keyboard input? My mistake? Any clarification will be highly appreciated.

I'm actually new to bar-code and winCE development and if it helps, I'm familiar with the following languages (in-order): C#, VB6, VB.Net, C, Java. Any suggestion on the quickest way to get the job done? I believe it's not a hectic job, but I'm stuck on where to begin.

Just tell me in case any further clarification is needed. Thanks in advance!

**Edit#1:**

Here's what I tried so far (Assuming Barcode Scan works just like keyboard input):
(Using VB.Net for Windows CE 5.0 Device under VS2005)

```
Private Sub barcodeTB_TextChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles barcodeTB.TextChanged
    If (Len(barcodeTB.Text) = 10) Then     'If 10 digits ID have been scanned..
        Using writer As IO.StreamWriter = New IO.StreamWriter("log.txt", True)
            writer.WriteLine(barcodeTB.Text & " " & DateTime.Now)
        End Using
        barcodeTB.Text = ""    'reset TextBox
    End If
End Sub
```

It works just fine when I input the code manually. But nil when I tried to scan my bar-code.

**Edit#2:**
There are several PDFs provided in their website: http://www.scantech-id.com/en/support/download.php?pin=42676d021abeff1e479180ffeb4240e5

I'm perfectly sure that the scanner is installed in COM3 port if it helps! Still trying to figure this out.

**Edit#3:**
So this is my last attempt: To read it directly via the DataReceived from COM3 Port.

I set a timer so that it sends the data transmitted every 1 second if there's any. It works nicely as the textbox only get updated when I scan my bar-code. However, the output is not in a desirable format. What am I doing wrong? See below:
[image: Screenshot]

And here's the code:

```
Private Sub SerialPort1_DataReceived(ByVal sender As System.Object, _
    ByVal e As System.IO.Ports.SerialDataReceivedEventArgs) _
    Handles SerialPort1.DataReceived
    Q.Enqueue(SerialPort1.ReadExisting())
End Sub

Private Sub Timer1_Tick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
    SyncLock Q
        While Q.Count > 0
            receivedTB.Text &= Chr(13) & Chr(10) & Q.Dequeue
        End While
    End SyncLock
End Sub
```

Comment: is there some text in barcodeTB when you doing scan ?

Comment: Unfortunately not all bar-code scanning uses the keyboard input. You'll have to find out how your particular device does it. Possibly via a USB port with a driver, or, if you're really unlucky, it's built in to the motherboard of the device.

Comment: +matzone Nope, nothing.

+A Pale Shadow: Hi, actually this is the device I'm working on: http://www.barcodeconnexions.co.uk/barcode_connexions_website_071.htm

I'm still trying to figure out about how the device work as of now.

Comment: Sorry for this stupid question .. USB or COM devices ?

Comment: @matzone It's COM I believe. The scanner is built-in in COM3 port as mentioned above. And it's not a stupid question of course!

Comment: have you try to use USB to COM connector ?

Comment: @matzone I'm not sure about that one.. Can't find much about it. But try to see my edit#3 above. I think it'll be best if I can intercept the ID scanned directly via the COM3 port. Any further pointer perhaps?